# Expected values and cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability

I'm stuck on the following:

Consider a random variable $X$ whose probability mass function is given by:
$$
p(x)=
\begin{cases}
0.1,\quad &x=-3\\
0.2, &x=0\\
0.3, &x=2.2\\
0.1, &x=3\\
0.3, &x=4\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Let $F(x)$ be the corresponding cdf. Find $E(F(X))$.

Thanks.

Thanks for the edits, Stefan. This is not a homework problem. I'm studying for my P1 exam after being out of school for some time.

So far, I have: 
$$
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad &x<-3\\
0.1, &-3<=x<0\\
0.3, &0<=x<2.2\\
0.6, &2.2<=x<3\\
0.7, &3<=x<4\\
1,& 4<=x
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Can you find the _values_ that the _random variable_ $F(X)$ takes on? For example, if $X = 3$, what is the value of $F(3)$? You should be able to arrive at the conclusion that $F(X)$ is a _discrete_ random variable taking on values in $[0,1]$ with various probabilities and then be able to compute the mean of $F(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Compare
$$
\mathbb E(F(X))=\sum_xp(x)F(x)=\sum_xp(x)\sum_{y\leqslant x}p(y)
$$
with
$$
1=\sum_xp(x)\cdot\sum_yp(y)=2\sum_xp(x)\sum_{y\leqslant x}p(y)-\sum_xp(x)^2
$$
to deduce that
$$
\mathbb E(F(X))=\frac12\left(1+\alpha\right),\qquad\text{with}\ \alpha=\underline{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ }.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You take the values of $F(X)$ and multiply each times the original $p(x)$, and add those together.

$0.1(0.1)+0.3(0.2)+0.6(0.3)+0.7(0.1)+1(0.3) = 0.62 $